# The eigenfunction of modified 1-laplace equation

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, harmonic-analysis

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^2$ be a bounded, smooth boundary domain. I am interested in the following operator
$$
-\operatorname{div}\left(\frac{\nabla u}{\sqrt{|\nabla u|^2+\epsilon}}\right)=0.
$$
where $\epsilon>0$ is a fixed constant, and we apply Neumann boundary condition.

My question: can we somehow have the eigenfunction and eigenvalue of this operator such that the following hold?
$$
-\operatorname{div}\left(\frac{\nabla u}{\sqrt{|\nabla u|^2+\epsilon}}\right)=\lambda u, \tag 1
$$
If we do, what would be the regularity of those eigenfunctions? and can they form an Orthonormal basis of $L^2$ as the eigenfunction of standard Laplace operator $-\Delta$ does?

Thank you!

---

My idea:

First of all, I would like to make sure $(1)$ indeed has a solution. It looks to me we may study the following minimizing problem
$$
E(u)=\int_\Omega \sqrt{|\nabla u|^2+\epsilon}dx-\lambda \int_\Omega u^2dx
$$
and I am trying to apply mountain pass theorem on it, although $E(0)\neq 0$...

---

This question is also posted in MO [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/244112/the-eigenfunction-of-modified-1-laplace-equation). I did my research for couple of days but have no luck. So I put it here for more help.

Comment: This type of question is indeed suitable for this site, and not for Math Overflow.  The question itself does look to be really tough.

Comment: It is not clear if any $u$ with norm one satisfy your equation. It's nonlinear